# Check spaces in mysql field

Tags: mysql

```
 select name from emp_profile;

    Result:
     tom@rj6.com
```

In the above result how to determine whether there are trailing spaces in it or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RTRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim) removes trailing spaces.

If `RTRIM(name)` varies from `name`, there are trailing spaces in the field.

Related functions are `LTRIM()` (trims starting spaces) and `TRIM()` (both sides)

As a side note, I would recommend removing trailing spaces (and other invalid data) during input time on application level, not in the database.

Comment: Does this indicate the trailing space.I want the query to show the trailing spaces..

Comment: @Rajeev how do you mean "show"? Do you want to select the trailing spaces only?

Comment: @Rajeev to select only rows that have trailing spaces, use `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE RTRIM(name) != name;` to replace, use e.g. `SELECT REPLACE(name, ' ','_') FROM table`;

Answer (score 1):

If name is a char field it wil not have trailing spaces as far as I can ascertain varchar's do have trailing spaces.

An easy way to check for trailing whitespace to check the length against the trimmed length. rtrim()